# Append java version result to line above?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is there a way I can append the line "java version or permissioned denied" to the line above with a , between them ? I'm looking to do this for data manipulation purposes on bash for red hat 6 .

Thanks

```
/apps/orautil/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/client_1/jdk/jre/lib/
java version "1.6.0_75"

/export/file/node/jre1.8.0_171/lib/
java version "1.8.0_171"

/test/jre1.8.0_171_linux/lib/
java version "1.8.0_171"

/usr/local/tripwire/te/agent/jre/lib/
sh: line 4: /usr/local/tripwire/te/agent/jre/lib/../bin/java: Permission denied
```

Expected results

```
/apps/orautil/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/client_1/jdk/jre/lib/,java version "1.6.0_75" 

/export/file/node/jre1.8.0_171/lib/,java version "1.8.0_171" 

/test/jre1.8.0_171_linux/lib/,java version "1.8.0_171" 

/usr/local/tripwire/te/agent/jre/lib/,sh: line 4: /usr/local/tripwire/te/agent/jre/lib/../bin/java: Permission denied
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show what your desired output would look like? And ideally add the command you've tried, and how it failed?

Comment: /apps/orautil/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/client_1/jdk/jre/lib/,java version "1.6.0_75"

/export/file/node/jre1.8.0_171/lib/,java version "1.8.0_171"

/test/jre1.8.0_171_linux/lib/,java version "1.8.0_171"

/usr/local/tripwire/te/agent/jre/lib/,sh: line 4: /usr/local/tripwire/te/agent/jre/lib/../bin/java: Permission denied

Comment: Please [edit] the question instead of adding to it in the comments, the formatting in the comments is very limited.

Comment: Got it. I correct the format on the question.

Answer (score 0):

with bash

```
while true; do 
    IFS= read -r line1
    IFS= read -r line2
    IFS= read -r line3
    status=$?
    printf "%s, %s\n%s\n" "$line1" "$line2" "$line3"
    (( status != 0 )) && break
done < file
```

and with awk

```
awk '
    /java version/ || /Permission denied/ {printf ", %s\n\n", $0; next} 
    {printf "%s", $0} 
' file

# which can also be written as
awk '{
    format = (/java version/ || /Permission denied/) ? ", %s\n\n" : "%s"
    printf format, $0
}' file
```

or, by manipulating the input/output field and record separators

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS="\n"; RS=""; OFS=", "; ORS="\n\n"}
    {$1 = $1; print}
' file

# or, more tersely
awk '{$1=$1}1' FS='\n' RS='' OFS=', ' ORS='\n\n' file
```